# How to compare data returned in each iteration of a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that returns data from an array based on certain condition. How can I go about comparing the data received that is received on each iteration of the loop.

I want to:

1. Validate if the data returned on the second iteration matches the
   data returned on the first iteration. If it matches, do something. If no match, do something else.
2. Validate if the data returned on the third iteration matches the data returned on the second iteration. If it matches, do something. If no match, do something else.

A cut down sample of what my code looks like:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($data[0] as $data) {
  if ($data == criteria_1) {
      $count +=1;
      echo '$data'.$count;
      break;
  } elseif ($data == criteria_2) {
      $count +=1;
      echo '$data'.$count;
      break;
  } elseif ($data == criteria_3) {
      $count +=1;
      echo '$data'.$count;
      break;
  }   
}
```

Comment: an example of the data would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding exactly what you're trying to do here, but this general pattern should work: save the data that you want to compare in a variable before the end of of the loop block, then check against that variable during the next iteration. You can use `if ($count > 0)` to avoid performing this check on the first go-round.

```php
$count = 0;
foreach ($data[0] as $data) {
  // If this is at least the second iteration of the loop,
  // compare the current data to the data from the previous
  // iteration.
  if ($count > 0) {
      if ($data === $previous) {
          // Match.
          // ...
      } else {
          // No match.
          // ...
      }
  }

  if ($data == criteria_1) {
      $count +=1;
      echo '$data'.$count;
      break;
  } elseif ($data == criteria_2) {
      $count +=1;
      echo '$data'.$count;
      break;
  } elseif ($data == criteria_3) {
      $count +=1;
      echo '$data'.$count;
      break;
  }   

  // Save the current data so we can access it in the next iteration.
  $previous = $data;
}
```